# Fast way to find the neighboor of pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, matrix

I am programming for task that finds the neighbor of a given pixel `x` in image `D`that can formula as:

[image]

The formula shown pixels `y` which satisfy the distance to pixel `x` is 1, then they are neighbor of pixel `x`. This is my matlab code. However, it still takes long time to find. Could you suggest a faster way to do it. Thank you so much

```
%-- Find the neighborhood of one pixel
% x is pixel coordinate
% nrow, ncol is size of image 
function N = find_neighbor(x,nrow,ncol)

    i = x(1);
    j = x(2);
    I1 = i+1;
    if (I1 > nrow)
        I1 = nrow;
    end
    I2 = i-1;
    if (I2 < 1)
        I2 = 1;
    end
    J1 = j+1;
    if (J1 > ncol)
        J1 = ncol;
    end
    J2 = j-1;
    if (J2 < 1)
        J2 = 1;
    end
    N = [I1, I2, i, i; j, j, J1, J2];
```

For example: `ncol=128; nrow=128; x =[30;110]` then output

```
N =31    29    30    30; 110   110   111   109]
```

For calling the function in loop

```
x=[30 31 32 33; 110 123 122 124]
for i=1:length(x)    
N = find_neighbor(x(:,i),nrow,ncol);
end
```

Comment: If you are using this function within some nested loops, it would make more sense probably to get rid of those loops for faster execution.

Comment: Right. I used it in the loop, Actually, it will call that function about 4000 times. Is it possible to reduce the computational time?

Comment: Those function calls might be killing the performance there. Show us those nested loops code?

Comment: @Please tell us what you are doing with these pixels. Either `conv2` or `blockproc` is probably the right choice.

Comment: @Divakar: Let see my update. Daniel: The conv2 is applied for whole image. However, my task only works in a few pixels in image. That pixels are choose in advance.

Comment: @john2182 As Daniel also said, it would help us understand the "bottleneck" if you could share with us how you might be using those neighboring pixels.

Comment: Yes. I just find these neighbor pixels from a given pixel. The expected output is N

Comment: You are overwriting the values obtained from `find_neighbor` into `N` at each iteration of `N = find_neighbor(x(:,i),nrow,ncol)`. So, could you write down the expected outcome for `x=[30 31 32 33; 110 123 122 124]`?

Comment: It is very easy. You can used the my above example of  x =[30;110] . Note that 30 and 110 are pixel coordinate in image row 30th and column 110th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using `bsxfun`:

```
% define four neighbors as coordinate differences
d = [-1 0 ; 1 0 ; 0 -1 ; 0 1]';
% add to pixel coordinates
N = bsxfun(@plus, x, permute(d, [1 3 2]));
% make one long list for the neighbors of all pixels together
N = reshape(N, 2, []);
% identify out-of-bounds coordinates
ind = (N(1, :) < 1) | (N(1, :) > nrow) | (N(2, :) < 1) | (N(2, :) > ncol);
% and remove those "neighbors"
N(:, ind) = [];
```

The `permute` is there to move the "dimension" of four different neighbors into the 3rd array index. This way, using `bsxfun`, we get the combination of every pair of original pixel coordinates with every pair of relative neighbor coordinates. The out-of-bounds check assumes that `nrow` belongs to the first coordinate and `ncol` to the second coordinate.

With

```
ncol=128;
nrow=128;
x = [30 31 32 33; 110 123 122 124];
```

the result is

```
N =

    29    30    31    32    31    32    33    34    30    31    32    33    30    31    32    33
   110   123   122   124   110   123   122   124   109   122   121   123   111   124   123   125
```

Different neighbors of different pixels can end up to be the same pixel, so there can be duplicates in the list. If you only want each resulting pixel once, use

```
% remove duplicates?
N = unique(N', 'rows')';
```

to get

```
N =

    29    30    30    30    31    31    31    32    32    32    33    33    33    34
   110   109   111   123   110   122   124   121   123   124   122   123   125   124
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. However, I measure time consuming between my method and your method. It shown that my method is more faster.

Comment: Hi @john2182, that's very unlikely theoretically, and I can't reproduce this practically. If I run your and my code on an x that contains 1 million points, your code needs 3.758 seconds and mine 0.190 seconds.

Comment: Be sure to use `tic` and `toc` for benchmarking, and run it on at least a few thousand points – otherwise the measurements are meaningless.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it again. Because I just test a few pixels

Comment: @A.Donda, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's performance is horrible when calling small functions many time. The Matlab approach is to do vectorize as much as possible. A vectorized version of your code:

```
  function N = find_neighbor(x,nrow,ncol)
  N = [min(x(1,:)+1,nrow), max(x(1,:)-1,1), x(1,:), x(1,:); x(2,:),   x(2,:),min(x(2,:)+1,ncol), max(x(2,:)-1,1)];
  end
```

and usage

```
x=[30 31 32 33; 110 123 122 124]   
N = find_neighbor(x,nrow,ncol);
```

BTW, for pixels on the border , your solution always gives 4 neighbors. This is wrong. the neighbors of (1,1) for examples should be only (2,1) and (1,2), while you add two extra (1,1).
The solution to this is quite simple - delete all neighbors that are outside the image

```
  function N = find_neighbor(x,nrow,ncol)
  N = [x(1,:)+1, x(1,:)-1, x(1,:), x(1,:); x(2,:), x(2,:),x(2,:)+1, x(2,:)-1];
  N(:,N(1,:)<1 | N(1,:)> nrow | N(2,:)<1 | N(2,:)>ncol)=[];
  end
```

Comment: Thank Ophir Gvirtzer. Check second solution again. It gives wrong answer for x=[30;110]